ssh tunneling connecting but netstat not showing port is listening
On a remote server, I ran:
 ssh -v -L 5110:some_host_name:<remote_port> local.server

It produced:
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5110 forwarded to remote address <redacted>
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 5110.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5110.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: proc
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8

Here it's saying it's listening on port 5110, but when I ran
netstat -tuln | grep 5110

it doesn't produce anything which seems to indicate 5110 is not listening.
